# .NET Core 5.0 error 400 after redirected to login page from Quickbooks OAuth, issue resolves if i revisit the Url by pressing enter

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, session-cookies, c#-5.0, login-page

I have a .NET Core 5.0 application which authenticates & integrates Quickbooks with OAuth and then redirects to the application login page. When I click login, I get an http 400 error and cookie for ASP.NET Core Identity is not created, yet but if select the url and press enter then it just works fine, anybody has any suggestions on this?

I tried a couple of things like adding authorize in that controller form where I am redirecting and also tried several cookie settings I found but nothing worked so far

Comment: Could you please share some code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: actually sharing code is not possible for me due to my corporate policies ,

Comment: I can explain -: 
The app is running in a dot net core 5 environment & I have integrated QuickBooks in it, 
situation -: after I click on Connect QuickBooks, it calls a method to redirect to a specific URL and that URL redirects me to the login page of the application after authentication of QuickBooks, and then the login page (opens up with some route values to the page from where I Click on Connect QuickBooks ),  and then click on the login button, 400 error came up, but if revisit the same URL then it works fine

Comment: the problem is  user logged in is not being retained after i got redirected to a URL and opens up login page(URL to specific action is correct)  and when i hit login , 400 occurs , its not even hitting the mail login function but if i refresh it works